# curl in C without libcurl

Tags: c, linux, curl

I try tu run curl in C with this  command (without libcurl)
`curl -X GET "https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/klines?symbol=&interval=&limit=&startTime=&endTime=`

I created this script (in linux mint)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int status = system("curl -X GET \"https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/klines?symbol=&interval=&limit=&startTime=&endTime=\"");
```

when I compile, I get this error:

```
test.c:3:14: error: initializer element is not constant
    3 | int status = system("curl -X GET \"https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/klines?symbol=&interval=&limit=&startTime=&endTime=\"");
      |              ^~~~~~
```

Anyone  can explain me  why return this  error?

Answer (score 3):

You need a `main` function in C. This is covered in the first chapter of your C text book.

You probably want something this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int status = system("curl -X GET \"https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/klines?symbol=&interval=&limit=&startTime=&endTime=\"");
   ...
}
```

Comment: sorry is  first  time  in C  is  much better if  i deepen about  C   thanks  again